# How to iterate through a node list and compare strings

Tags: c

I have pretty new to the concept of linked lists in C. I spent many hours to come up with a logic to do the following but all in vain. I am trying to iterate through a linked list. Lets say each nodes represents a person and each person (node) have two traits. For example:

```
struct person {
    struct person *next;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char trait_01[TRAIT_LENGTH];
    char trait_02[TRAIT_LENGTH];
}

Node 1: Sarah (trait 1: Soccer Trait 2: Designer)
Node 2: Carl (trait 1: Baseball Trait 2: None)
Node 3: Andrew (trait 1: Soccer Trait 2: Walking)
Node 4: John (trait 1: Cricket Trait 2: Designer)
Node 5: Cara (trait 1: Surfer Trait 2: Walking)
Node 6: Ben (trait 1: Racing Trait 2: Acting)
Node 7: Andy (trait 1: Walking Trait 2: Surfer) 
Node 8: Jack (trait 1: Designer trait 2: Soccer )

**Output:**
Soccer
Designer
Baseball
Walking
Cricket
Surfer
Racing 
Acting
```

Output has no repetition of any traits and it does not include the word "None" and it should be in sequence i.e. Trait 1 is printed first and then Trait 2.

Is there anyone who could help ?

Comment: Where are you finding difficulty in this? Do you know how to create a simple linked list?

Comment: Creating linked list is not an issue.  I can create, allocate me memory, free memory and all . I am just struggling with the logic here.

Comment: Let's say that you come across a node whose value you are about to print (while traversing) - you compare the trait values of that node to the nodes before it (starting from `head` node) & skip printing if the value matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment that the logic is not clear, Since there wasn't any evidence from your `output` that `trait1` can be compared to `trait2` to identify the duplicate traits, underwritten code is just removing (not printing) duplicate values of `trait1` from the already occured values in `trait1` & same with `trait2`:

```
//AFTER CREATING THE LINKED-LIST

temp=head;             //temp is a temporary node for traversal
int indicator1=0;
int indicator2=0;

while(temp)
{
    temp1=head;       //temp1 is a temporary node 

    if(temp==head)   //all of the traits of head node is to printed with the "None" logic requirement of course
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->trait_01,"None")!=0)
            printf("%s\n",temp->trait_01);

        if(strcmp(temp->trait_02,"None")!=0)
            printf("%s\n",temp->trait_02);
    }
    else //if trait is already present in earlier nodes then it is not printed and of course "None" logic is followed
    {    
         while(temp1!=temp)
         {
             if((!strcmp(temp->trait_01,temp1->trait_01))&&(indicator1==0)&&(!strcmp(temp->trait_01,temp1->trait_02)))
             {
                 indicator1=1;
             }

             if((!strcmp(temp->trait_02,temp1->trait_02))&&(inicator2==0)&&(!strcmp(temp->trait_02,temp1->trait_01)))
             {
                 indicator2=1;
             }
         }
         if((indicator1==0)&&(strcmp(temp->trait_01,"None")))
             printf("%s\n",temp->trait_01);
         if((indicator2==0)&&(strcmp(temp->trait_02,"None")))
             printf("%s\n",temp->trait_01);

    }
    temp=temp->next;

    indicator1=0;
    indicator2=0;
}
```

Explanation: The first while loop `while(temp)` traverses through every node of the linked list (the `while` condition is violated when `temp` is `NULL` i.e. end of the linked list).

The second while loop `while(temp1!=temp)` -> the code tries to match the trait values of the `temp` node with the trait values of nodes lying in the linked list before `temp` (between `head` node and `temp`), `temp1` represents the nodes lying on/after `head` node and before `temp` node.

The condition `!strcmp(str1, str2)`v(`strcmp` returns `0` when strings are same) says that i the two strings are same then the `if` condition will be satisfied and `indicator` will be set to **1** indicating that a trait value of `temp` node (`trait_01` or `trait_02`) is same
as trait value of some previous node `temp1`. When this indicator is set to `1` we don't print the trait value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you heaps. I'm going to try this as soon as I am on my pc. I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks alot..   Just one last thing, I have added two more nodes above (Node 7 and node 8). Are you able to tweek the code to cater to those  conditions as well ? Thanks heaps again.

Comment: Thank you again. sure will do. Could you please just explain a bit the first loop condition and the second loop condition? and does the !strcmp(str1, str2) means it wont proceed if the string comparison is matched?

Comment: @BiLAL Done!! Please check now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash-set for the purpose:

You iterate through the linked list, and everytime you get a trait, check if it is in the hash-set or not. If it is in the hash-set, don't print it, and if it doesn't exist, print it and add it to the hash-set. In this process, you should ignore all the strings that are "None".

Hash-sets don't exist in C libraries, you need to make your own that too with a good string hashing function.

If you don't want to use hash-sets right now, then you have to consider an inefficient solution.

Maintain a string array (`char**`), call it `words`.

Iterate through the list and for every trait, check if it is in the `words` array or not. If it is there, don't print it, otherwise, print it and add it to the `words` array. You need to do it manually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LENGTH 25
#define TRAIT_LENGTH 15
#define MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH 10

struct person {
    struct person *next;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char trait_01[TRAIT_LENGTH];
    char trait_02[TRAIT_LENGTH];
};

int find_in_array (char words[][TRAIT_LENGTH], int size, char trait[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if (strcmp (words[i], trait) == 0)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct person* head = NULL;

    /* Initialize linked list here */

    char words[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH][TRAIT_LENGTH];
    int size = 0;

    for (struct person* p = head; p != NULL; p = p -> next)
    {
        if (strcmp (p -> trait_01, "None") != 0 && find_in_array (words, size, p -> trait_01) == 0)
        {
            printf ("%s\n", p -> trait_01);
            strcpy (words[size++], p -> trait_01);
        }

        if (strcmp (p -> trait_02, "None") != 0 && find_in_array (words, size, p -> trait_02) == 0)
        {
            printf ("%s\n", p -> trait_02);
            strcpy (words[size++], p -> trait_02);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is `C` not `C++`

Comment: Thank you for your quick  response but i think u misunderstood the question.

Comment: @BiLAL oh yes, wait.